AWS RDS MariaDB stalls have to reboot
We have been running AWS RDS MariaDB instance for multiple years with zero issues. This week two of our instances have stalled.
This required us to hard reboot the RDS manually from AWS Console. Only after a hard reboot (5-10 minutes) does the instance come back up and respond.
Symptoms

Database is completely unresponsive
Log pane in AWS Console shows "no logs" which is not right because definitely are logs
Monitoring and Logs stops reporting metrics entirely
EBSByteBalance% metrics experience sheer drop to 0
Database is showing as "Available"

Below is what the EBSByteBalance% looks like:

Analysis

No change to our workloads
External traffic looks completely normal and expected, no strange looking external interactions
No bad queries when looking at database engine
No issues reported in AWS Health Dashboard

What is going on here? This has happened on two database with completely different types of workloads.

Do you have AWS Support, or could you get AWS support for a month? This is a question for them really, they have access to more information than you do. Also, you could try stopping and starting the database in order to move it to a new server, rather than restarting it which I think leaves it on the same server.

@Tim thanks, if it happens again I will consider doing that :)
